# Can I use jcifs/samba client in a spring boot app to access a NFS file share

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, nfs, smb, jcifs

I'm building a spring boot app which reads file out of a file share. I was told the file share is a NFS share.
Can i use the jcifs library or any smb library to read files from a NFS share? Or do i need some NFS specific java library to read files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See some answers here: [Access to NFS-Share from Java-Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741365/access-to-nfs-share-from-java-application).

So, you still can use Spring Integration SMB extension with its JCIFS foundation and read from that NFS service via CIFS protocol.

Otherwise you are on your own to implement something using some NFS-specific library.

Comment: I have now used the spring integration SMB extension. I am now getting Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Signature validation failed 
Getting,
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Unable to initialize share: smb://domain;null@servername:445/sharename; nested exception is jcifs.smb.SmbException: Signature validation failed
        at org.springframework.integration.smb.session.SmbShare.init(SmbShare.java:119)
*************************
Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Signature validation failed
   at jcifs.smb.SmbSessionImpl.sessionSetupSMB2(SmbSessionImpl.java:615)

Comment: To add on, I did not provide any username password when i create the smbsessionfactory. Could this error be due to that? I was told the app server IP which would be accessing that share has been whitelisted at their end.

Comment: You need to see if you can disable signature verification somehow: https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng/issues/57. Sorry, I'm not so good with SMB to lead to properly.